# Why Doesn't dt[,ncol(dt)] Return Column Contents?

Tags: r, datatable, data.table

I've edited this question based on comments by @akrun (thank you!), realizing I didn't accurately ask my question.

I'm confused why the following doesn't return the contents of the last column in a data table.

```
> dt <- data.table(A=c(10,10,10),B=c(20,20,20),C=c(30,30,30))
> dt[,ncol(dt)]
[1] 3
```

If I use `with=F` it behaves as I would expect, returning the last column as a data table

```
> dt[,ncol(dt),with=F]
   C
1: 30
2: 30
3: 30
```

This returns the same result as `dt[,3]` which makes sense. But why is it not true that `dt[,ncol(dt)] = dt[,3]`? From `?data.table`,

> When j is a vector of column names or positions to select (as in data.frame). There is no need to use with=FALSE anymore.

Doesn't `ncol(dt)` return a vector of column positions, a vector of length one? Why doesn't `dt[,ncol(dt)]` return the contents of the last column?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We need `drop = FALSE` for `data.frame`

```
df[,ncol(df), drop = FALSE]
```

as by default it is `TRUE` if we check the `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

---

For the `data.table`, we need `with = FALSE`

```
 dt[, ncol(dt), with = FALSE]
```

and it is mentioned in the `?data.table` help

> When j is a character vector of column names, a numeric vector of column positions to select or of the form startcol:endcol, and the value returned is always a data.table. with=FALSE is not necessary anymore to select columns dynamically. Note that x[, cols] is equivalent to x[, ..cols] and to x[, cols, with=FALSE] and to x[, .SD, .SDcols=cols].

Comment: Thank you @akrun, but I'm wondering why `dt[,ncol(dt)]` doesn't equal `df[,ncol(df)]`. I understand that I need to include `drop=F` for a data frame and `with=F` for a data table to get a table returned, but I want a vector returned from the data table. For this example, why does `dt[,3]` not equal `dt[,ncol(dt)]`?

Comment: @jeromeResearch you can use `[[` to subset `dt[, .SD[[ncol(.SD)]]]`

Comment: I hadn't thought of that one, but yes there a number of ways to get the last column. Another option: `dt[,ncol(dt),with=F][[1]]`. But I'm still confused why `dt[,ncol(dt)]` returns `ncol(dt)`. I would expect data table and data frame to behave the same way here, but they don't.

Comment: @jeromeResearch they don't have the same default options and their behavior is different.  So, you can't expect it to work same

Comment: I appreciate you discussing this with me. Forget about expecting it to behave like a data frame. For this example, why does `dt[,ncol(dt)]` return `3` instead of the contents of the third column?

Comment: @jeromeResearch it is evaluating the `ncol` which is 3 and is returning that index